# Помогите понять, почему не работает суммеслимн в ARRAYFORMULA (гугл таблицы)

Tags: массивы, google-spreadsheet

В гугл таблицах использую формулу:

={"Маржа";ARRAYFORMULA(ЕСЛИ($B2:$B={""};;СУММЕСЛИМН('Сводная маржа'!H2:H;'Сводная маржа'!F2:F;D2:D;'Сводная маржа'!C2:C;B2:B)))}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы подсчитать сумму маржи по каждому менеджеру определённого отдела в определённый день. Таблица большая, за год. Ничего не получается - вместо значений выдаёт нули.

При этом в этой же таблице прекрасно работает счётеслимн практически с таким же условием и суммеслимн с обычными цифрами или простыми критериями типа ">" или "<".

Не понимаю, в чём причина, прошу помочь разобраться. Таблица для теста: [тык](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nVVMoyn7yZn_1e2L4kLB5SVXWJ0BLKe3oRUydhMUcq8/)

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS заменяем на SUMIF с объединением диапазонов проверки и условий.

Было:

```
={"Маржа";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B=0;;SUMIFS('Сводная маржа'!H2:H;'Сводная маржа'!F2:F;D2:D;'Сводная маржа'!C2:C;B2:B)))}
```

Стало:

```
={"Маржа";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B=0;;SUMIF('Сводная маржа'!C2:C&'Сводная маржа'!F2:F;B2:B&D2:D;'Сводная маржа'!H2:H)))}
```

(Спасибо @contributorpw за [пример на его сайте](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-formulas-arrayformula/).)